# getting Java to work in Cygwin

Tags: java, linux, cygwin

I just downloaded cygwin to run some java programs and i need to set up java.  I tried to download the standard linux packages and got the error `Cannot execute binary files`

After some research I figured I had to point it to my windows java folder, so I ran

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin"
```

and it seems to work (java -version shows my java info).  However it seems to screw up my linux bash settings, afterwards I cant do basic stuff such as ls, sh, etc.  it gives command not found error and the only way is to change the PATH variable back to my cygwin folder.

how can i get java "installed" in cygwin?

Comment: I'm happy to be wrong, but I am always skeptical of having spaces in cygwin paths. So I usually install Java to C:/Java/... to avoid any issues with spaces in path names for it. Also, do you have your JAVA_HOME environment variable set?

Comment: yup - $ echo $JAVA_HOME
cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_51

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running the linux binaries with java -version, what does "which java" print? Is your PATH somehow invalid, what is does "echo $PATH" print? That shouldn't screw up your PATH, it should work even after "export PATH=$PATH:/foo/bar/baz".

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
Within cygwin, use bash.
Also install java8, older versions lack key features.
```

Second:

```
Add the following lines to your .bashrc file:
echo "javac     :`which javac`"
echo "jar       :`which jar`"
echo "java      :`which java`"
echo "ant       :`which ant`"
```

When you start a new bash shell, it will echo the versions of these four java essentials.
Run each one with no arguments and you should get four appropriate complaints. If they don't run, then you need to install them.

Then create a directory called src and create HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World from main!");
    }
}
```

In the same directory, create HelloWorldAsPackage.java:

```
package src;

public class HelloWorldAsPackage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World In a Package (Directory) called 'src'!");
    }
}
```

Then create the bash script runOneCase.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Listing $1.java"
echo "=================================================="
cat $1.java
echo "=================================================="
echo "Compiling $1.java"
echo "+ javac $1.java"
javac $1.java
echo "+ cd $2"
cd $2
echo "Running $1.java"
echo "+ java $3$1 $4"
java $3$1 $4
echo "=================================================="
```

Then create the bash script runThemAll.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "CASE 1: HelloWorld"
runOneCase.bash HelloWorld . "" ""

echo "CASE 2: HelloWorld as a Package"
runOneCase.bash HelloWorldAsPackage .. src. ""
```

Now run the script: runThemAll.bash by typing it at the cygwin prompt.

If you get the following output, you can consider java installed under cygwin.

```
CASE 1: HelloWorld (Hit Return)

Listing HelloWorld.java
==================================================
public class HelloWorld
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                System.out.println("Hello World from main!");
        }
}
==================================================
Compiling HelloWorld.java
+ javac HelloWorld.java
+ cd .
Running HelloWorld.java
+ java HelloWorld
Hello World from main!
==================================================
CASE 2: HelloWorld as a Package (Hit Return)

Listing HelloWorldAsPackage.java
==================================================
package src;

public class HelloWorldAsPackage
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                System.out.println("Hello World In a Package (Directory) called 'src'!");
        }
}
==================================================
Compiling HelloWorldAsPackage.java
+ javac HelloWorldAsPackage.java
+ cd ..
Running HelloWorldAsPackage.java
+ java src.HelloWorldAsPackage
Hello World In a Package (Directory) called 'src'!
```

Comment: what do you mean by Within cygwin, use bash?

Comment: This example uses bash, one could also have used Bourne shell (sh), tsh, csh, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need cygwin to run java in windows. You can set the path environmental variable to enable its use. Since you allready have java installed you're half way there.

```
1. Right-click on 'My Computer' and select 'Properties'.(i.e. go to System Properties)
2. Click on the 'Environment variables' button under the 'Advanced' tab.
3. Alter the 'Path' variable so that it also contains the path to the Java executable.
     Example, if the path is currently set to 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32', then change your path to read 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin'.
```

Once you complete these steps you can run java from the command prompt or even in cygwin as it uses the System path variable as well.

Comment: One does need to realize that Windows command prompt sucks balls.

Comment: Setting up the PATH variable enables java to be run from command line, whether your in cygwin or windows command prompt.

Comment: @caburse wake me up when I can run a bash script in a windows command line and have it cooperate with java. Some of us have unix-based programming environments and I highly doubt I can do the kind of parsing I do in bash in a cmd shell.

Answer (score 0):

oh haha rookie mistake.  you have to append the java source directory to PATH, not export it directly., so `export PATH=$PATH:"/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin"` instead of `export PATH="/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin`